# Can I Use A Question With Multiple Responses From A Microsoft Forms To @ Mention People In A Microsoft Teams Message Using Microsoft Power Automate

Tags: office365, microsoft-teams, power-automate, microsoft-forms

Hello Stack Overflow community,
I have a Microsoft form that automatically @ mentions me on a Microsoft Teams Channel which is working great at the moment. However, I would like there to be a question which prompts the user to select multiple additional team members to be notified within the message.
[Example Of Multiple Choice Teams Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEajb.png)
Currently I am just using < at>MyEmail@Example.com< at/> to tag myself.
I imagine I could use a formula to detect how many responses have been filled out in the question and @ mention people using that information although I am not sure how.
[Example Of Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHqdT.png)

Thanks!

Comment: This is a time-related question, if you wait an hour after the first question then you could list all replies and add the @ mentions, that or predict the future. By using a full fledged Bot you could edit the first reply, to add more @ mentions, but PA cannot do that

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find the direct way but I did find a workaround. Here are the steps

- I created a form with multiple choice question :

[image]

- In the flow I initialized two variable textMessage, temp(which I will use later)
- Output from *Form question* is coming as string: `["adelev@example.com","diegos@example.com"]`, so I removed character `[`, `]`, `"` in *Compose* using
  `replace(replace(replace(FormValue,'[',''),']',''),'"','')`
- After doing replace we got the string as `adelev@example.com,diegos@example.com`
- Then in another *Compose 2* `split(outputs('Compose'),',')` here we got output as array: `["adelev@example.com","diegos@example.com"]`
- Then I put *Apply to each* on `outputs('Compose_2')` and did manipulation on the string. As shown in below screenshot[image]
- Then in *Post a message as the Flow bot to a channel* -> Message -> Hi variables('textMessage')
- Success! - Power automate mention multiple user.